# I want to redirect a user after iframe is shown

Tags: redirect, iframe

I have it set up so the user can click an image and it will drop down an iframe. I want them to be redirected after they see it for a few seconds. I searched for hours not finding the right thing, help?

Comment: "drop down an iframe" - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: I have a animation setup so it looks like the area is being dropped down
 I basically just need it to redirect after the image is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(() => window.location = 'http://www.google.com', 2000)
```

This will send a user to another site after 2 seconds.  Put this in the block that shows the iframe, et voila.